# Unary plus with numbers?

Tags: math-mode

This is driving me nuts...

I need to write out an explicit plus sign, like (q, 1, +1).

But LaTeX just swallows the '+' sign...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, fourier, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{lmodern, fourier}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

      \begin{tabular}{>{\(}l<{\)}*{3}{|>{\(}c<{\)}}}
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\boldmath\(q\)\unboldmath} &
          \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\boldmath\(0\)\unboldmath} &
          \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\boldmath\(1\)\unboldmath} &
          \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\boldmath\(b\)\unboldmath} \\
        \hline
        q_0 & (q_0, 0, +1) & (q_0, 1, +1) & (q_1. b, -1) \\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Werner have you seen the column specification? it seems to add `\(` and then `\)` around each entry. To the OP: if you load `lmodern` before `fourier` it seems to resolve the issue

Comment: @cmhughes, right. Leaving out lmodern does fix this nonsense. Thanks!

Comment: The package `fourier` uses different encodings for math fonts than the standard ones, so it shouldn't be used along other font packages that use `OMS` or `OMX`. This doesn't affect `stmaryrd` and `amssymb` that use direct calls of the slots for their symbols.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is the fourier package that ate your + with that you get the warning

```
Missing character: There is no   in font lmsy10!
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, 
%fourier,
 mathrsfs
}
\usepackage{lmodern, fourier}
                      %%% OK
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{>{\(}l<{\)}*{3}{|>{\(}c<{\)}}}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\boldmath\(q\)} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\boldmath\(0\)} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\boldmath\(1\)} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\boldmath\(b\)} \\
    \hline
    q_0 & (q_0, 0, +1) & (q_0, 1, +1) & (q_1. b, -1) \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```